# How to configure virtual host in loopbackJS?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Is there a way to currently do virtual hosting with loopbackJS (i.e. host multiple domains under one IP)? I would like to maintain different version of app different subdomains but in one ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option is to use an nginx server.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name abc.xyz.com ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_connect_timeout      300;
        proxy_send_timeout         300;
        proxy_read_timeout         300;


    }

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/xyz-access_log ;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/xyz-error_log ;

}
```

use this as the virtual host

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use something like Nginx to serve multiple LoopBack instances though.

Comment: That'd definitely be the best and most efficient way to do it imo. More scalable too.